# How to count events over time and group by conditions based on datetimes with Dataframes in R

Tags: r, dataframe, datetime, group-by, data-wrangling

I am being faced with the challenge of building a table by doing some data wrangling with two different datasets.

DataSet A: Has the information of purchases in a clothing store with the variables: name of client, date of purchase, agent and product purchased during a period of time t.

```
df1 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~NAME, ~PRODUCT, ~AGENT,        ~DATE_PURCHASE,
  "Karen",   "M_14",  "X_1", "8-25-20021 18:21:28",
  "Jean",   "M_78",  "X_3", "8-26-20021 18:11:06",
  "Jean",   "M_71",  "X_4", "8-26-20021 18:21:01",
  "Jean",   "M_64",  "X_4", "8-27-20021 20:21:59",
  "Keith",   "M_57",  "X_4", "8-27-20021 20:21:02",
  "Alba",   "M_50",  "X_1", "8-28-20021 20:21:03",
  "Alba",   "M_43",  "X_3", "8-29-20021 20:21:04",
  "Alex",   "M_36",  "X_2", "8-25-20021 20:21:05"
)
```

Dataset B: Has the information of clients who have called the CX SERVICE line of the company during a period of time t and stores the variables name of client, date of call, and type of call.

```
df2 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~NAME,        ~TYPE,         ~DATE_OF_CALL,       
  "Karen",   "COMPLAIN", "8-26-20021 18:21:28", 
  "Jean", "CX_SERVICE", "8-27-20021 18:11:06",
  "Jean",   "COMPLAIN", "8-28-20021 18:21:01", 
  "Jean", "CX_SERVICE", "8-29-20021 20:21:59",
  "Keith", "CX_SERVICE", "8-29-20021 20:21:02", 
  "Alba",   "COMPLAIN", "8-30-20021 20:21:03", 
  "Alex", "CX_SERVICE", "8-25-20021 21:21:05", 
)
```

I have to build a dataset with the following: I have to create a new variable called "x attempt" that will let me know if this is the first, second, third, etc call of the custumer on the line, and for each custumer bring back on the table the last product bought prior to the very last call received including the type of the call. I know that this may sound confusing so here is an example of the desired table:

```
NAME   | x attempt | product | TYPE      | DATE_CALL           | DATE_PURCHASE       |
Jean|  |     3     |  M_64   |CX_SERVICE | 8-29-20021 20:21:59 | 8-27-20021 20:21:59 |
```

This result would be correct because on the record... this would be Jean´s third call on the line, the type of the last call was for CX_SERVICE on  8-29-20021 20:21:59 and the last product she bought was a M_64 on 8-27-20021 20:21:59 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you might have made a mistake with the year, so I removed the extra zeroes in the year (2021). I see that you are using tibbles, hence I will provide a `tidyverse` method of solving this problem.

The idea of the provided code is to first handle the tibbles separately, and then join them by the common denominator `NAME`.
This should do it:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~NAME, ~PRODUCT, ~AGENT,        ~DATE_PURCHASE,
  "Karen",   "M_14",  "X_1", "8-25-2021 18:21:28",
  "Jean",   "M_78",  "X_3", "8-26-2021 18:11:06",
  "Jean",   "M_71",  "X_4", "8-26-2021 18:21:01",
  "Jean",   "M_64",  "X_4", "8-27-2021 20:21:59",
  "Keith",   "M_57",  "X_4", "8-27-2021 20:21:02",
  "Alba",   "M_50",  "X_1", "8-28-2021 20:21:03",
  "Alba",   "M_43",  "X_3", "8-29-2021 20:21:04",
  "Alex",   "M_36",  "X_2", "8-25-2021 20:21:05"
)

df2 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~NAME,        ~TYPE,         ~DATE_OF_CALL,       
  "Karen",   "COMPLAIN", "8-26-2021 18:21:28", 
  "Jean", "CX_SERVICE", "8-27-2021 18:11:06",
  "Jean",   "COMPLAIN", "8-28-2021 18:21:01", 
  "Jean", "CX_SERVICE", "8-29-2021 20:21:59",
  "Keith", "CX_SERVICE", "8-29-2021 20:21:02", 
  "Alba",   "COMPLAIN", "8-30-2021 20:21:03", 
  "Alex", "CX_SERVICE", "8-25-2021 21:21:05", 
)

(df1_mod <- df1 %>%
  mutate(DATE_PURCHASE = as.POSIXct(DATE_PURCHASE, format = "%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S")) %>%
  group_by(NAME) %>%
  summarise(product = PRODUCT[DATE_PURCHASE == max(DATE_PURCHASE)], # retrieve product with the most recent date_purchase
            DATE_PURCHASE = max(DATE_PURCHASE), # retrieve most recent date_purchase
            .groups = "drop"))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#>   NAME  product DATE_PURCHASE      
#>   <chr> <chr>   <dttm>             
#> 1 Alba  M_43    2021-08-29 20:21:04
#> 2 Alex  M_36    2021-08-25 20:21:05
#> 3 Jean  M_64    2021-08-27 20:21:59
#> 4 Karen M_14    2021-08-25 18:21:28
#> 5 Keith M_57    2021-08-27 20:21:02

(df2_mod <- df2 %>%
  mutate(DATE_OF_CALL = as.POSIXct(DATE_OF_CALL, format = "%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S")) %>%
  group_by(NAME) %>%
  summarise(`x attempt` = n(), # retrieve amount of calls, which is n() (the amount of rows in the group)
            TYPE = TYPE[DATE_OF_CALL == max(DATE_OF_CALL)], # retrieve type of call from most recent call
            DATE_OF_CALL = max(DATE_OF_CALL), # retrieve most recent date_of_call
            .groups = "drop"))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>   NAME  `x attempt` TYPE       DATE_OF_CALL       
#>   <chr>       <int> <chr>      <dttm>             
#> 1 Alba            1 COMPLAIN   2021-08-30 20:21:03
#> 2 Alex            1 CX_SERVICE 2021-08-25 21:21:05
#> 3 Jean            3 CX_SERVICE 2021-08-29 20:21:59
#> 4 Karen           1 COMPLAIN   2021-08-26 18:21:28
#> 5 Keith           1 CX_SERVICE 2021-08-29 20:21:02
  
left_join(df1_mod, df2_mod, by = "NAME")
#> # A tibble: 5 x 6
#>   NAME  product DATE_PURCHASE       `x attempt` TYPE       DATE_OF_CALL       
#>   <chr> <chr>   <dttm>                    <int> <chr>      <dttm>             
#> 1 Alba  M_43    2021-08-29 20:21:04           1 COMPLAIN   2021-08-30 20:21:03
#> 2 Alex  M_36    2021-08-25 20:21:05           1 CX_SERVICE 2021-08-25 21:21:05
#> 3 Jean  M_64    2021-08-27 20:21:59           3 CX_SERVICE 2021-08-29 20:21:59
#> 4 Karen M_14    2021-08-25 18:21:28           1 COMPLAIN   2021-08-26 18:21:28
#> 5 Keith M_57    2021-08-27 20:21:02           1 CX_SERVICE 2021-08-29 20:21:02
Created on 2021-04-10 by the reprex package (v0.3.0)
```

Comment: PLY I have to praise you for being so kind and helping my out you have no idea just how much this means to me and how deeply thankful I am I have been working on this problem for days, I just went to your page to continue to learn from your other responses thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I read this as requiring output of one row per call, but I think the above will return one row per customer, my answer is a lot more verbose, but for each call it will return the info for the most previous call and purchase, thats probably not what you want, but I wrote it up anyway :-)

```
    library(tidyverse)
    library(lubridate)
    
    df1_purchases <- data.frame(cust_name = paste0("Name_", sample(LETTERS, replace = TRUE, 1000)),
                      product = paste0("Product_",sample(1:500, replace = TRUE, 100)),
                      agent = paste0("Agent_Name_", sample(LETTERS[1:5], replace = TRUE, 1000)),
                      purchase_datetime = ymd_hms(paste0(sample(2000:2019, 
                                                                replace = TRUE,
                                                                1000),
                                                         "-",
                                                         sample(1:12, 
                                                                replace = TRUE, 
                                                                1000),
                                                         "-",
                                                         
                                                         sample(1:28,
                                                                replace = TRUE,
                                                                1000),
                                                         "-",
                                                         sample(1:24, 
                                                                replace = TRUE,
                                                                1000),
                                                         "-",
                                                         sample(1:59,
                                                                replace = TRUE,
                                                                1000),
                                                         "-",
                                                         sample(1:59, replace = TRUE, 
                                                                1000)))) 
    
    df2_calls <- data.frame(cust_name = paste0("Name_", sample(LETTERS, replace = TRUE, 1000)),
               type = paste0("calltype_", sample(c("Complaint", "Service"), replace = TRUE, 1000)),
               call_datetime = ymd_hms(paste0(sample(2000:2019, 
                                                         replace = TRUE,
                                                         1000),
                                                  "-",
                                                  sample(1:12, 
                                                         replace = TRUE, 
                                                         1000),
                                                  "-",
                                                  sample(1:28,
                                                         replace = TRUE,
                                                         1000),
                                                  "-",
                                                  sample(0:24, 
                                                         replace = TRUE,
                                                         1000),
                                                  "-",
                                                  sample(0:59,
                                                         replace = TRUE,
                                                         10000),
                                                  "-",
                                                  sample(0:59, replace = TRUE, 
                                                         1000)))) 
    
    output_df <- data.frame(cust_name = NULL,
                            prev_calls = NULL,
                            prev_purchase_item = NULL,
                            prev_call_datetime = NULL,
                            prev_purchase_datetime = NULL)
    
    f <- function(df2_calls, df1_purchases, cust, this_call_datetime) {
    
    df_calls <- df2_calls %>% filter(cust_name == cust)
    
    df_purchases <- df1_purchases %>% filter(cust_name == cust)
    
    if(sum(df_calls$call_datetime < this_call_datetime) < 1) {
      cust_name <- cust
      prev_calls <- 0
      prev_call_type <- NA
      prev_call_date_time <- NA
      
    } else {
      
      df_calls <- df2_calls %>% filter(call_datetime < this_call_datetime)
      
      most_recent_call_number_for_cust <- df_calls %>%
        pull(call_datetime) %>%
        which.max()
      
      cust_name <- cust
      prev_calls <- length(df_calls$cust_name)
      prev_call_type <- df_calls$type[most_recent_call_number_for_cust]
      prev_call_date_time <- max(df_calls$call_datetime)
    }
    
    if(sum(df_purchases$purchase_datetime < this_call_datetime) < 1) {
      prev_purchase_item <- NA
      prev_purchase_datetime <- NA
      
    } else {
      most_recent_purchase_for_cust <- df_purchases %>%
        filter(purchase_datetime < this_call_datetime) %>%
      pull(purchase_datetime) %>%
        which.max()
      
      df_purchases <- df_purchases[most_recent_purchase_for_cust,] 
      
      
      prev_purchase_item <- df_purchases$product
      
      prev_purchase_datetime <- df_purchases$purchase_datetime 
    }  
    
    new_row <- data.frame(cust_name = cust,
                           prev_calls = prev_calls,
                           prev_purchase_item = prev_purchase_item,
                           prev_call_datetime = prev_call_date_time,
                           prev_purchase_datetime = prev_purchase_datetime,
                           this_call_datetime = this_call_datetime)
    
    new_row
    
    }
    
    number_of_call_rows <- nrow(df2_calls) 
    
    for(i in 1:number_of_call_rows) {
     output_df <- rbind(output_df, 
        f(df2_calls, 
          df1_purchases,
          df2_calls$cust_name[i],
          df2_calls$call_datetime[i]))
    }  
      
    glimpse(output_df)
```